# How to get rid of "Object may be null" error when uploading a file with React (typescript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I tried to upload a file with refs but I always get this error: *Object is possibly 'null'*.

Refs must be used, as well as a class component. No hooks are allowed. I'm really stuck.

My code so far:

```
  import React from 'react';

  export default class Form extends React.Component<unknown> {
  
  private picture: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
  
  constructor(props: unknown) {
    
    super(props);
      this.picture = React.createRef();
    }
    state = {
      picture: '',
    };

    handleChange = () => {
      this.setState({
      picture: this.picture.current?.files[0], //this line throws an error
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Your Form</h1>
        {/* input fields */}
        <form>
          <label
            htmlFor="fileupload"
            className="custom-file-upload forLabel"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            Picture
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="picture" ref={this.picture} />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not upload images of code.

Comment: Post your code, instead of an image of it. Making people who want to help you type all your code in order to test is not fair.

Comment: have you tried `picture: !!this.picture.current?.files && this.picture.current?.files[0]`?